# printf the whole unit of an array

Tags: c

Suppose such a snippet of minimal code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int *ptr = arr;
int main(void)
{
    printf("The value of arr is %d, the address of the arr is %ptr", *ptr, ptr);
}
```

Get it outputs:

```
$ ./a.out
The value of arr is 1, the address of the arr is 0x107d57018tr
```

I'd like to print the whole unit of array, so tried to replace `%d` with `%s` in the printf function.
Nonetheless, it report error:

```
first_c_program.c:6:70: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("The value of arr is %s, the address of the arr is %ptr", *ptr, ptr);
                                ~~                                   ^~~~
                                %d
1 warning generated.
```

How could I printf the whole unit of the array.

Comment: What does "whole unit of the array" mean? Are you trying to print all of the values in the array? You can't do that without a loop.

Comment: A C string with ASCII chars 1, 2, 3 and no 0 terminator? Errrr. What is your actual question - this is a very bad attempt to solve something else.

Comment: You can print an array ***if and only if*** the array is a `char` array, and there is a NUL terminator in the array (in other words, the array is a C string). For any other case, there is no built-in mechanism in C to print the whole array. You need to do it one element at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print each value individually, like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  printf("%d", arr[i]);
```

`printf("%d", *arr)` prints the first value of the array as an integer. It is equivalent to `printf("%d", arr[0])`, just as `printf("%d", arr[i])` and `printf("%d", *(arr + i))` are interchangeable. `printf("%ptr", arr)` prints the address of the array (i.e. the address of the first value) as an address.

As others have pointed out, `%s` expects `char *`, see `printf(3)`. If you're interested, `printf` is just a wrapper to `vfprintf`, which implements a jump table, which, in turn, ends up in a `write` syscall after a series of vtables and macros, whilst the formatting stuff happens in `vfprintf.c`. You can read the details in [this blog post](http://blog.hostilefork.com/where-printf-rubber-meets-road/) and in the [code for glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;h=fc370e8cbc4e9652a2ed377b1c6f2324f15b1bf9;hb=3321010338384ecdc6633a8b032bb0ed6aa9b19a).

Comment: `printf("%ptr", arr)` prints the value of the pointer in an implementation-defined manner *followed by* `tr`.